# Custom NET MAUI Splash screen

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui, .net-maui

I am trying to make a splash screen in **.Net MAUI** that contains a gradient background and an animated logo.

I have seen the tutorials on how to make a simple splash:

```
  <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Images\splashscreen.svg" Color="#512BD4" />
```

However, I can't figure out how to customize a splash without using a full ready background, because I don't know what the perfect dimension would be for different platforms.

**Some examples:**

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41tAp.png)

[Example animated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCf35.gif)

Thanks.

NB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, if you want to custom the Splash screen , you can the drag an image with a gradient background as you want into the Resources\Splash folder of the project, and then change the iamge size by setting `BaseSize` like below:

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\yourspalshscreen.svg" BaseSize="256,256"/>
```

Also, MAUI doesn't support `Animation` yet, for more details, you can refer to this [open request](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3300).

[Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=android).

Comment: Can we set border color to image in splash screen?