# How to add a custom splash screen in MAUI?

Tags: android, splash-screen, maui

I have a basic MAUI project and I want to set an SVG file as the splash screen.

I have tried to modify the csproj file using the code below:

As you can see the photo is cropped in a circle
[image]

How can I make the splash screen display the entire photo?

Comment: I do not see "the code below".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (at least not without going a long way using a separate splash screen activity).

That's a limitation of Android: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

The picture also needs to fit into the frame and should be squared. You can set the base size for that in the `<MauiSplashSceen>` build action in your `.csproj` file.

You may also be interested in this: [Custom NET MAUI Splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73465373/custom-net-maui-splash-screen)

There currently also is a bug in MAUI's resizetizer which requires giving the SVG file an entirely new name each time you want to change it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74336491/4308455

I've written a blog post about the Splash Screen in MAUI, which might also be of interest: https://ewerspej.hashnode.dev/lets-customize-the-splash-screen-of-a-maui-app

Answer (score 1):

For the device which android version is lower than 12.0, you can use the following code to make the image full full the splash screen.

1. Delete the old splash image in the Resources/Splash folder.
2. Put your image in it and set it's build action as MauiSplashScreen
3. Create a xml file in the `Platforms\Android\Resources\drawable\maui_splash.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash" //the splash is your image's name 
        android:dither="true"
        android:gravity="fill"/>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

And then, your image will show in the full splash screen.

For the device which android version is lower than(or =) 12.0, the android system changed the api about the splash screen. The resource code about is the `FrameLayout` contains a `ImageView` and we can't set the `ImageView` `layout_width` and `layout_height`. For more information, you can check the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70346451/17455524).

Comment: I tried your solution following all the steps but it doesn't work with Android 12 physical device. There is a issue opened here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/9797, I think we have to follow it for the resolution